# grails.tomcat.jvmArgs when multiple Grails apps are on the same Tomcat7 (Xmx, Xms, etc)

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, memory

Back story:

I have 3 Grails applications I want to run on the same Tomcat7 server. I am able to run 2 at a time without a problem but it is when I try to deploy the third I get a Java crash. Alternatively the app fails to deploy or it deploys but Java crashes within the hour.

/etc/default/tomcat7 has the following to limit Java's maximum memory usage:
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

In each app's BuildConfig.groovy I can specify a bunch of arguments.
eg: grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-Xms96m",  "-Xmx128m"]

Question:

Are the arguments passed via grails.tomcat.jvmArgs only for their respective app (each app can have different memory demands/limits) or does the first deployed set global arguments for all applications?

Is something else happening?

Answer (score 2):

The setting `grails.tomcat.jvmArgs` is only used for the development time Tomcat instance started by `grails run-app`, not for when you deploy to an external Tomcat instance. In that case the settings can be customized using `CATALINA_OPTS`

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=”-Xms256m -Xmx512m”
```

These settings apply to all apps deployed to Tomcat, so if you have 3 Grails apps you need to set sufficient memory for the three.